# How do I convert an Est file to a shapefile?

Tags: convert

I need help converting an Est(Streets and Trips) file to shapefile or some other format that ArcGIS can read. I haven't been able to find any luck using Google and my go to program Alteryx can't read Est files. Does anyone have any insight on how I can convert this data format?

Comment: I don't know the answer you need, but some potential responders may be curious if you are comfortable with solutions working in a command line window or you require a GUI. Similarly, if you open that `.est` file using Notepad or better, Notepad++, what do you see? Like, is it readable data or binary formatted? Finally, have you seen [this utility software for GPSes](http://www.gpsu.co.uk)?

Comment: I'm pretty much a beginner with command line apps. I've used commands in the command prompt window before but unfortunately any technical jargon is likely to go over my head. I don't have notepad++ but in regular notepad there is hardly any text with a lot of shapes and numbers. I think this means its a binary file.

Comment: EST to GPX  (or CSV) > https://www.gps-data-team.com/convert.php then use the geoprocessing tool in arcgis to gpx to features http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/gpx-to-features.htm

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer at [this website](https://forums.garmin.com/forum/mac-windows-software/windows-software/1767-option).    After converting to GPX you could use GPS Babel to create a shapefile.

*1: you need to download some free software that will convert a microsoft street and trips file (.est) to a file type that the garmin will understand (.gpx) file. I use a program called itnconv that allows me to pick which file type i want to export the .est file to. take that .gpx file and open it in mapsource. double click on it in mapsource and do a recalculate, then send it to your device. It will show up in your my data folder and you can then do an import to have it show up in your custom route folder. You may be able to bypass the mapsource portion of this,but i'm stll looking into that.

2: but microsoft street and trip 2010. it now has an option to download into gps. It will show up in your my data folder and you can then do an import to have it show up in your custom route folder. you may have to do a recalculate once its there, but i'm not sure how to do that within the garmin (or whether that happens automatically when you import and engage the route). does anyone know the answer to that?*